# git rebase could not execute editor

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, git-config

I'm attempting to squash some git commits using rebase. When I run this:

```
git rebase -i HEAD
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/lib/git-core/git-rebase: 1: eval: /usr/bin/mate: not found
Could not execute editor
```

I've attempted to change the git config editor variable but I haven't gotten it to work. Right now my config file shows the following:

```
[core]
    editor = /usr/bin/vim
```

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04

Any ideas?

Comment: how about using git reset --hard 'commit'?

Comment: Have you checked both `$GIT_DIR/config` and `~/.gitconfig`?

Comment: Yes I've checked both of them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do something like that

```
$ git config --global core.editor emacs
```

where **emacs** paste name of your editor

Answer (score 4):

Check to make sure `GIT_EDITOR` is not set in your environment.  It takes precedence over core.editor.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I added `editor = /usr/bin/vim` to the git config file for the specific project as well as my system but that didn't work. Is that what you're talking about or should I be looking for something else?

Comment: I think the point is that an environment variable `GIT_EDITOR` may override your project and/or global settings, which is useful sometimes.

Comment: I don't think that's my problem. Its a Rails project and the project's  git config file says the same thing as my core.

Comment: You should check with `env | grep GIT_EDITOR`.  If it comes empty, then it's not the problem.  I suspect it's not empty and is set to `/usr/bin/mate`.

Comment: I am also having this problem and when I do env | grep GIT_EDITOR    I get GIT_EDITOR=/usr/bin/mate -w.  How do I change that?

Comment: @ruby_newbie It's most likely in your ~/.bashrc file (if you're using bash as your shell).  You can run `unset GIT_EDITOR` in that shell to remove the environment variable, but you'll want to check your ~/.bashrc and fix that to make sure it's not getting set in the first place.

Comment: the only thing in my .bashrc profile is "export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting"

Comment: I have also checked the following:   .bashrc, .bash_it, .bash_profile, .gitconfig, .profile, and .zshrc and I only see VI in some no references to mate or textmate.

Comment: If it's set as soon as you enter the shell, it might be useful to try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299886/find-out-where-an-environment-variable-was-last-set-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

As additional measure you can look at the sequence.editor config option:

```
[sequence]
    editor = /usr/bin/vim
```

or override it's behavior with `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim` env variable.

More details you can find on: [git-config.txt-sequenceeditor](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-sequenceeditor)