# Some bash variables are being overwritten

Tags: macos, bash, shell, bash-it

I am using [bash-it](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it) in my Mac OSX terminal. However, lately i have been having problems related to the `EDITOR` and `GIT_EDITOR` variables.

In a custom bash file i set those variables clearly via:

```
# Make Sublime the default editor
export EDITOR="subl";
export GIT_EDITOR="subl --wait";
```

However, something is overwriting those variables as when i do `export -p` the values assigned are:

```
declare -x EDITOR=" -w"
declare -x GIT_EDITOR=" -w"
```

I have checked the other sourced files to see if they are being overwritten by a plugin somewhere but with no luck.

Would appreciate any pointers on how to debug and fix this.

Thanks

Comment: check [find-out-where-an-environment-variable-was-last-set-in-bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299886/find-out-where-an-environment-variable-was-last-set-in-bash)

Comment: Great ! Thanks @amdixon .. i caught it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by having Bash-it's [textmate plugin](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/blob/a044ad5f59887b254851d1b80a42ee8f1c382a3c/plugins/available/textmate.plugin.bash#L4) enabled. It tries to define the `EDITOR` and `GIT_EDITOR` variables based on your local textmate installation:

```
export EDITOR="$(which mate) -w"
export GIT_EDITOR=$EDITOR
```

If you don't have the `mate` command on your path, if will set the variables to what you have seen, just `-w`. This is an error in Bash-it, there should be an `if` statement around these definitions. I have created a [pull request](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/pull/526) to fix that.

If you're not using TextMate, simply disable the `textmate` plugin:

```
bash-it disable plugin textmate
```

Then open a new shell window, and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks @nwinkler i got that from debugging what was setting those variables. Disabled the plugin and all is good now :)

Comment: Thanks, good to hear. Have fun with Bash-it and please feel free to open issues or contribute pull requests on the GitHub repo.